# pr2 tutorials still worth?

Tags: catkin, pr2, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering whether it was worth digging into the pr2 tutorials. They seemed to be reference a few releases ago to get started with ROS but they really seem outdated now (no support in hydro, no catkin support, GDB supports cturtle and diamondback...). I have just gone through the basic tutorials (catkin oriented) and if I were to start the pr2 tutorials I would actually need to go through them again but in the rosbuild version... I actually fear to get lost in a mixture of catkin (not so well understood), rosbuild (not known at all) and pr2 specific things.

I guess this is more or less the same situation for all ROS newbies... So what do you think? And is there a modern equivalence to the pr2 tutorials?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185742/pr2-tutorials-still-worth?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi arennuit,

we at Clearpath are working over this summer on upgrading the PR2 to Hydro (that includes the tutorials and documentation as well).

Most of the PR2 packages have been catkinized in source but not released/tested yet. That means, it will be highly beneficial to learn the PR2 ecosystem. It will be supported, and is being supported right now by Clearpath Robotics.

Edit: Hydro has been released and Indigo development is scheduled for February 2015. The tutorials should have been updated, as well as instructions on installing Hydro with the WG->Clearpath Robotics modifications that will have to be made to your sources list. For more details visit https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/categories/200217239-PR2

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not expect a clearer answer. Thanks a lot DevonW!

PS: do you target indigo or a later version?

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-16**:
We're working on Hydro right now. Officially, I can't say when Indigo is coming out as we're still working on Hydro, but I can tell you that we have had discussions on doing it :)

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-16**:
Awesome thanks for answering (and for your great work :))